# Org-mode source code block not executed

Tags: org-mode

I want to have:
- a source code block fontified on export
- but not executed
- and used as input for another source code block.

I can have it fontified in org-mode and not exported if I use a `begin_example` block. But can I let it be fontified on export (to html or latex) es well? Or, vice versa, can I suppress a `begin_src` from being executed?

What I have so far is this:

```
#+name: uninterpreted_sh
#+header: :exports code
#+begin_src sh
echo "Direct"
#+end_src

#+name: uninterpreted
#+begin_example sh
echo "Direct"
#+end_example

#+header: :exports both
#+header: :results output
#+begin_src sh :stdin uninterpreted
VALUE=$(cat)
echo "I got: $VALUE"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: I got: echo "Direct"
```

There I can get `uninterpreted_sh` fontified and can use `uninterpreted` as stdin.

A last resort might be to supress the `begin_example` from beeing exported altogether?

Note: ther `results` I get from the last source block is exactly what I want.

Comment: src blocks aren't evaluated with the `:exports code` argument. They are evaluated when you pass them as the argument to `:stdin`. If you change your `begin_example` block to a `begin_src` block, doesn't that give you what you want?

Comment: unfortunately no, because then the shell will be called with `echo "Direct"` writing `Driect`to stdout which then is used as result and as stdin for the next block. But I want the whole source block as is to be put as input.

Comment: In other words, I wand to get as result `: I got: echo "Direct"`, and not `: I got: Direct`.

Comment: I would be happy if an example block wiith a language argument would be highlighted. Surprisingly the example block looks like a source block with correct language specific mode in org buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, although it's not perfect.

I advice the export function of the source block language in question:

```el
(defun org-babel-execute-exports-code-around (org-fun &rest args)
  "Do not execute code blocks that exports code."
  (let ((exports (cdr (assoc :exports (cadr args)))))
    (if (string= exports "code")
        (car args)
      (apply org-fun args))))
(advice-add 'org-babel-execute:shell :around #'org-babel-execute-exports-code-around)
```

Then I get what I wanted with the following org file:

```
#+name: uninterpreted_sh
#+header: :exports code
#+begin_src sh
echo "Direct"
#+end_src

#+header: :exports both
#+header: :results output
#+begin_src sh :stdin uninterpreted_sh
VALUE=$(cat)
echo "I got: $VALUE"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: I got: echo "Direct"
```